# yum install 389-ds (Directory Server) on Redhat Linux not working

Tags: linux, yum

I am trying to install 389-ds (Directory Server) on Redhat Linux.

> $ yum install 389-ds ...  Could not retrieve mirrorlist
>   http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=generic&type=free&release=5.0
>   error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host" Error:
>   Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository:
>   jpackage-generic. Please verify its path and try again

When i try to visit this http://jpackage.org site from web-browser, it is not reachable.

Any idea?

Comment: Uh.... remove it.

Comment: u mean remove the jpackage*.repo file from /etc/yum.repos.d?

Comment: Right now I have access to http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=generic&type=free&release=5.0 . It looks like you have network problems. Recheck your network settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a 3 yr old transient problem of connecting with a web site.  It's long been overtaken by events, so no longer needs solving, and cannot be replicated.